# List value is getting reset every time the for loop runs. How to store all the list values inside a list in Java?

Tags: java, list

I have a list of keys which I am iterating over to call a function and that function returns a list of items. I want to save the result of all the function call in the loop. Every time the for loop runs it resets the list values. I also tried with adding the function call result(returns list) into an another list. But that is also not not working.

Here is my code:

```
List<ProductDiscoveryConf> productDiscoveryConfsShared = new ArrayList<ProductDiscoveryConf>();
    for (String projectKey : projectKeys){
    //productDiscoveryConfs is a list
         productDiscoveryConfs = productDiscoveryConfService.getAllSharedDiscovery(projectKey);
         productDiscoveryConfsShared.addAll(productDiscoveryConfs);
       }
```

Comment: do you want to say `productDiscoveryConfs` is getting overrridden?

Comment: Yes every time the for loop runs it resets the list.

Comment: because you are assigning it everytime within the loop. And I assume you should be mistakenly using `productDiscoveryConfs` instead of `productDiscoveryConfsShared` after the loop

Comment: that's a function call that I need to do based on the different keys. Is there a way through which I can save the function call results.

Comment: share additional code after the loop so that we can see how it is used, then only we can comment

Comment: Changing the code to productDiscoveryConfs.addAll(productDiscoveryConfService.getAllSharedDiscovery(projectKey)); seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not assign value to the `productDiscoveryConfs` use add instead

```
List<ProductDiscoveryConf> productDiscoveryConfsShared = new ArrayList<ProductDiscoveryConf>();
    for (String projectKey : projectKeys){
    //productDiscoveryConfs is a list
         productDiscoveryConfs.addAll(productDiscoveryConfService.getAllSharedDiscovery(projectKey));
         productDiscoveryConfsShared.addAll(productDiscoveryConfs);
       }
```

Comment: you shouldn't addAll `productDiscoveryConfs` to `productDiscoveryConfsShared` within the loop, else it will create duplicate objects in the second list

Comment: @sidgate sure. If there are case that it can be duplications In that case better to use Set<> instead List<>